# Css not getting affected when using the same popup across multiple pages

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

By reading [this](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/popup-outside-multipage) I created a popup in main document outside `data-role="page"` as a direct child of `<body>`.
then the styles are not getting affected. Once I put inside `data-role="page"` styles are getting affected.

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize the popup yourself it is outside the page. For example, it the popup's id is 'popup-outside-page', you would need the following code on your first page:

```
$(function(){
    $( "#popup-outside-page" ).enhanceWithin().popup();
});
```